# How do I count the number of "+" in a function in google spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

So my function in A1 is 0,5+0,5+0,1
What I want to do is make a formula in B1 that counts the number of "+" elements in A1, how can I do this in google spreadsheet?

Comment: Questions about Google Spreadsheets are off topic and should be asked on webapps.stackexchange.com, unless they specifically involve your computer or browser.

Answer (score 0):

To find the specific character count you should substract specific character occurences from total length.

Let us say `A1` has value `5+1+3+4+3`

Type the following formula into `B1` cell:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",""))
```

`LEN(A1)` returns `9`

After that delete the searching character and count the length again.

`LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",""))` returns   `5`

So we get `+` sign count **4**.

This is for Excel.

You should change commas in the functions to semi-colons for Google Spreadsheets.

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"+";""))
```